# Renaming a filename by moving string from the back of the filename to the front

Tags: powershell, rename, filenames

I am trying to rename a filename by moving string from the back of the filename to the front:
PM - Prebills_10Aug20_Project _ 3359122596 H to:
3359122596 H PM - Prebills_10Aug20_

I'm trying to use this script and then strip out 'Project' afterward but can't get it to work:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { 
$_.Name -replace '(Project\d{*}) - (.*?)\.pdf$', '$1 - 
$2.pdf' } -WhatIf
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your example, e.g. with `backticks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  I don't know how general the pattern has to be.  Check out https://regex101.com for trying out regex's.

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.*)Project _ (\d{10} H)', '$2 $1' } -WhatIf

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:       C:\users\admin\PM - Prebills_10Aug20_Project _ 3359122596 H.pdf 
Destination: C:\users\admin\3359122596 H PM - Prebills_10Aug20_.pdf".
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this into your code:

```
Clear-Host
$FName = "PM - Prebills_10Aug20_Project_3359122596 H"
#-------- Start Here -------
$Parts = $FName.Split("_")
$FName = $Parts[3] + " " + $Parts[0] + "_" + $Parts[1]
#-------- End Here -----
$FName
```

Results: 3359122596 H PM - Prebills_10Aug20

It suppresses the trailing underline, you can add it back in if you want it. You could also easily remove the underline between Prebills and date and replace it with a space.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
 foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem *.pdf )){
        $temp = $file -split '_'
        $newname= $temp[3] + " " + $temp[1] + "_" + $temp[2] + "_"
        Rename-item "$file" -NewName "$newname"
    }
```